# ndtv Extra interval at the end

Tags: r

I have been trying to run the ndtv package to render a networkDynamic object and everything work except there was an extra time interval at the beginning and the end. The beginning interval is 0-1 and the one at the end is the last time point in the networkDynamic object plus 1. I deactivated all vertices in the 0-1 interval and it went away but that doesnt work on the one at the end for some reason.

I also tried to change the slice.par and still it didnt work. Its just there, the animation stops at the last correct interval and it just goes on an extra interval without changing

```
render.d3movie(net_dynamic, 
               displaylabels = TRUE,
               vertex.col="black", vertex.sides=50, 
               displaylabels=T, label.col="black", label.cex=1,
               label = "vertex.names",
               filename = "test_1.html",
               slice.par = list(start = 0, end = 7, interval = 1, aggregate.dur = 1, rule = 'latest'),
               animation.mode = "kamadakawai",
            )
```